# How can I convert varchar to numeric in visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Please help me,Im trying to do a fixed asset program in visual basic studio using sql server, Im stack in this.

I checked if my sql table data types match with the visual studio data types.

```
Public Class Equipos_de_Computacion
    Dim sql As String = ""


    Private Sub BtnInsertar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsertar.Click
        If (Me.txtCodigoInterno.Text = "") Then
            MsgBox("El campo idententificacion no puede estar vacio", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Atencion")
            Me.txtCodigoInterno.Select()
        Else
            Dim CodigoInterno As Integer
            Dim NumerodeSerie As Integer
            Dim NumerodeFactura As Integer
            Dim FechadeCompra As Date
            Dim Precio As Decimal
            Dim Acargode As String = ""
            Dim Estado As String = ""
            Dim Depreciacion As Decimal
            Dim Caracteristicas As String = ""


            CodigoInterno = Me.txtCodigoInterno.Text
            NumerodeSerie = Me.txtNumerodeSerie.Text
            NumerodeFactura = Me.txtNumerodeFactura.Text
            FechadeCompra = Me.DateTimePicker1.MinDate
            Precio = CDec(txtPrecio.Text)
            Acargode = Me.txtACargode.Text
            Estado = Me.txtEstado.Text
            Depreciacion = CDec(txtDepreciacion.Text)
            Caracteristicas = Me.txtCaracteristicas.Text

            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection = conn

            sql = "INSERT INTO [Equipos de Computacion] (CodigoInterno, NumerodeSerie, NumerodeFactura, FechadeCompra, Precio, Acargode, Estado, Caracteristicas, Depreciacion) "
            sql += "Values('" & CodigoInterno & "','" & NumerodeSerie & "','" & NumerodeFactura & "','" & FechadeCompra & "','" & CDec(Precio) & "','" & Acargode & "','" & Estado & "','" & Caracteristicas & "','" & CDec(Depreciacion) & ")"
            MsgBox(sql)
            cmd.CommandText = sql
            Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Registro insertado correctamente")

            Catch ex As Exception

                If ex.ToString.Contains("duplicate") Then
                    MsgBox("El registro ya existe en la base de datos")
                Else
                    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
                End If
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

it sends me converting varchar to numeric error.

Comment: You are trying to take a value that is a string and assign it to a variable that is an int (number)!   It would help if you could show us the exact line where the error happens. But either way... what you need to figure out is if the value you are trying to assign to a type if int can actually be converted to an int. If the value is "foobar" than it won't work. If the value is "32" then it will work.  If the value CAN b converted to an int, then you'll want to google "how to convert a string to an integer."

Comment: Im not able to insert decimal values but with CInt i got no problems. I want to insert decimal values.

Comment: please help me its urgent.

Comment: You have not answered the questions I asked in my first comment. 1) What is the exact line on which you are seeing the error?  2) What is the exact value you are trying to convert to an int?

Comment: Also, is the error happening in the C# code? Or the SQL query?

Comment: Line 40             Try
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                MsgBox("Registro insertado correctamente")

Comment: Precio or Price: money data type and Depreciacion or depreciation:decimal DT

Comment: I can't see your line numbers. But, if you are trying to execute a query, and this is where the error is happening, then the error is happening in SQL and not C#. So it's a database error.  What is the query that is executing on this line?

Comment: its In the c# code but as I told i got no problems when I change CDec With Cint but the registration goes wrong and I insert a rounded number.

Comment: sql = "INSERT INTO [Equipos de Computacion] (CodigoInterno, NumerodeSerie, NumerodeFactura, FechadeCompra, Precio, Acargode, Estado, Caracteristicas, Depreciacion) "
            sql += "Values('" & CodigoInterno & "','" & NumerodeSerie & "','" & NumerodeFactura & "','" & FechadeCompra & "','" & CDec(Precio) & "','" & Acargode & "','" & Estado & "','" & Caracteristicas & "','" & CDec(Depreciacion) & ")"
            MsgBox(sql) this is the query

Comment: Ok. Now we are making some progress. And, next, can you show me all of the value types for each of the database columns? For example, is CodigoInterno a varchar? Or an int? Or a bit? Or a datatime? Etc. I need to see this for all of the columns: CodigoInterno, NumerodeSerie, NumerodeFactura, FechadeCompra, Precio, Acargode, Estado, Caracteristicas, Depreciacion

Comment: Better yet, can you just show me the value of "sql" after you get past that line? I don't want to see the raw line of code. I want to see that full value of your "sql" variable after this line of code is executed.

Comment: codigointerno int, numerodeSerie int, numerodefactura int, FechadeCompra date, Precio money, acargode nvarchar(50), Estado nvarchar(50), Depreciacion decimal(18,0), caracteristicas nvarchar(50) all the information of my sql database

Comment: Ok. Now, what are the values you are trying to insert into each of those columns?

Comment: Im trying to introduce decimals in preciotext and the result in depreciation

Comment: hello are u still there?

Comment: I am. You didn't answer my last question.  "what are the values you are trying to insert into each of those columns?"

Comment: Im trying to insert everything according to its datatype per example im trying to introduce 2555,55 into precio.

Comment: i changed precio and depreciacion textboxs for numeric up downs

Comment: I'm not making myself clear. For example, you have a column called "codigointerno".  Can you give me an example of the *actual data* you are trying to insert into that column?

Comment: CodigoInterno 58888 , numerode Serie 5552222, NumerodeFactura 424324, FechadeCompra 5/08/19 Precio 15555,22 acargode: john Smith, estado: medium use depreciacion: precio * 0.25 caracteristicas: videocard: 9800 gtx

Answer (score 0):

Iam only able to insert integer numbers.With Cint
`Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Equipos_de_Computacion
    Dim sql As String = ""

```
Private Sub BtnInsertar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnInsertar.Click
    If (Me.txtCodigoInterno.Text = "") Then
        MsgBox("El campo idententificacion no puede estar vacio", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Atencion")
        Me.txtCodigoInterno.Select()
    Else
        Dim CodigoInterno As Integer
        Dim NumerodeSerie As Integer
        Dim NumerodeFactura As Integer
        Dim FechadeCompra As Date
        Dim Precio As Decimal
        Dim Acargode As String = ""
        Dim Estado As String = ""
        Dim Depreciacion As Decimal
        Dim Caracteristicas As String = ""


        CodigoInterno = CInt(Me.txtCodigoInterno.Text)
        NumerodeSerie = CInt(Me.txtNumerodeSerie.Text)
        NumerodeFactura = CInt(Me.txtNumerodeFactura.Text)
        FechadeCompra = CDate(Me.DateTimePicker1.Text)
        Precio = Me.nudPrecio.Value
        Acargode = Me.txtACargode.Text
        Estado = Me.txtEstado.Text
        Depreciacion = Me.NudDepreciacion.Value
        Caracteristicas = Me.txtCaracteristicas.Text

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmd.Connection = conn

        sql = "INSERT INTO [Equipos de Computacion] (CodigoInterno, NumerodeSerie, NumerodeFactura, FechadeCompra, Precio, Acargode, Estado, Caracteristicas, Depreciacion)"
        sql += "Values( '" & CodigoInterno & "' , '" & NumerodeSerie & "' , '" & NumerodeFactura & "' ,'" & FechadeCompra & "', '" & Precio & "' ,'" & Acargode & "','" & Estado & "','" & Caracteristicas & "','" & Depreciacion & "' )"
        MsgBox(sql)
        cmd.CommandText = sql
        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Registro insertado correctamente")

        Catch ex As Exception

            If ex.ToString.Contains("duplicate") Then
                MsgBox("El registro ya existe en la base de datos")
            Else
                MsgBox(ex.ToString)
            End If
        End Try
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgvEquiposdeComputacion.CellContentClick

End Sub

Private Sub BtnMostrar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnMostrar.Click
    Dim DS As New DataSet
    Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [Equipos de Computacion]", conn)
    DA.Fill(DS)

    dgvEquiposdeComputacion.DataSource = DS.Tables(0)
End Sub

Private Sub DateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DateTimePicker1.ValueChanged

End Sub

Private Sub BtnTotalDepreciacion_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnTotalDepreciacion.Click


    NudDepreciacion.Value = CDec(FormatNumber(nudPrecio.Value * 0.25, 2))


End Sub

Private Sub TxtPrecio_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub txtPrecio_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles nudPrecio.KeyPress
    nudPrecio.DecimalPlaces = 2
End Sub

Private Sub txtPrecio_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim VarMonedaDolares As Double
    VarMonedaDolares = nudPrecio.Value

    nudPrecio.Value = CDec(FormatCurrency(VarMonedaDolares, 2))
End Sub
```

End Class`